# 'git log' for a specific file is missing commits

Tags: git

Yesterday I committed some changes in a file named *Network.java*. Today I pulled with rebase from the origin. Now the changes are gone in the file.

What is more interesting is that if I run `git log -p` and search for *Network.java*, I see the commit with the changes. However, if I run `git log -p -- <path to Network.java>`, then I don't see my commit (it shows a commit made a week ago).

What is the explanation?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1130242/912144)? Note, this is the first "Related" question suggested by stackoverflow on the right. You may find your answer in one of those questions.

Answer (score 6):

You should run the same command with `--full-history`. It is because Git compacts the history.